# Store consts in a struct or a static class

Tags: c#, constants

If I have a set of string constants that I want to store similar to an `enum`, is it best to use a `struct` or a `static class`?  For example:

```
public struct Roman
{
    public const string One = "I";
    public const string Five = "V";
    public const string Ten = "X";
}

public static class Roman
{
    public const string One = "I";
    public const string Five = "V";
    public const string Ten = "X";
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A static class is more traditional in the C# environment.  The primary disadvantage of using a struct is that you could accidentally create an instance of it.  A static class will prevent this.  (Under the hood a static class is `abstract sealed`, so you cannot create an instance of it, nor can you derive from it.  You cannot make a struct abstract, nor can you make the no-argument constructor private, so there is no way to create an "unconstructable" struct.)

Neither approach will have any impact on performance or behavior of the constant values.